# Retrieve current login user from sqlite in toolbar

Tags: android, sqlite

i am developing a chat app and when I click on the login button I am redirected to MainActivity where I have a toolbar where I want to show the current login user name and profile pic using SQLite DB but I can't understand what should I code. what do I code in main activity to show current user name and default profile pic?

**DataBaseHelper**

```
package com.example.chatapp;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "USER_RECORD";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "USER_DATA";
    private static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL_2 = "USERNAME";
    private static final String COL_3 = "EMAIL";
    private static final String COL_4 = "PASSWORD";

    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , USERNAME TEXT , EMAIL TEXT , PASSWORD TEXT )");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean registerUser(String username , String email , String password){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_2 , username);
        values.put(COL_3 , email);
        values.put(COL_4 , password);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null , values);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean checkUser(String email , String password){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String [] columns = { COL_1 };
        String selection = COL_3 + "=?" + " and " + COL_4 + "=?";
        String [] selectionargs = { email , password};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME , columns , selection ,selectionargs , null , null , null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public User getLoggedInUser(String email){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String [] columns = { COL_2 };
        String selection = COL_3  + "=?";
        String [] selectionargs = { email };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME , columns , selection ,selectionargs , null , null , null);

        User user = new User();

        if(cursor != null){
            user.setUsername(cursor.getString(Integer.parseInt("username")));

            //If you want more data you can set your user properties
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.chatapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   CircleImageView  profile_image;
   TextView username;
   private DataBaseHelper myDB;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

      myDB = new DataBaseHelper(this);

   }
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
   {
      switch (item.getItemId()){

         case R.id.logout:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
            finish();
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/purple_700"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image">
            </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**User class**

```
package com.example.chatapp;

public class User {
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String imageURL;

    public  User(String id, String username, String imageURL)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.username=username;
        this.imageURL=imageURL;

    }

    public User() {

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }
}
```